# Reverse for 'password_change_done' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Tags: python, django

I am getting the following error in Django. Reverse for 'password_change_done' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []. I am not really sure why i am getting this error.

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.logout, name='logout'),
    url(r'^logout-then-login/$', auth_views.logout_then_login, name="logout_then_login"),
    url(r'^$', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),

    #change password urls
    url(r'^password-change/$', auth_views.password_change, name='password_change'),
    url(r'^password-change/done/$', auth_views.password_change_done, name='password_change_done'),
]
```

Traceback:
    Environment:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/password-change/

Django Version: 1.10.4
Python Version: 3.5.2
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'whitenoise',
 'crispy_forms',
 'business',
 'account']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/Users/Tommy/Desktop/django/directory/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/Tommy/Desktop/django/directory/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/Tommy/Desktop/django/directory/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/Tommy/Desktop/django/directory/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/decorators/debug.py" in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
  76.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/Tommy/Desktop/django/directory/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  149.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/Tommy/Desktop/django/directory/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  23.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/Tommy/Desktop/django/directory/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py" in inner
  47.         return func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/Tommy/Desktop/django/directory/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py" in password_change
  308.         post_change_redirect = reverse('password_change_done')

File "/Users/Tommy/Desktop/django/directory/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/base.py" in reverse
  91.     return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))

File "/Users/Tommy/Desktop/django/directory/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  392.             (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /account/password-change/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'password_change_done' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

html for page I am trying to open

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block title %}Change Your Password{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="offset-md-3 col-md-6">
    <h1>Change Your Password</h1>
    <p>Use the form below to change your password.</p>
    <form action="." method="post">
        {{form|crispy}}
        {% csrf_token %}
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Change the name of your URL from `password_change_done` to `auth_password_change_done` and use that name going forward

Comment: Karthik Ravindra - Tried it out did not work thanks though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you add `password_change` inside application's `url.py` you should to specify post_change url including application name using `post_change_redirect` argument:

```
url(r'^password-change/$', password_change, {'post_change_redirect': 'account:password_change_done'}, name='password_change'),
url(r'^password-change/done/$', password_change_done, name='password_change_done'),
```

where `account` is a namespace of application urls.

Comment: Still did not fix the issue. Thanks for your help though

Comment: @TomMyers what version of Django do you use? BTW can you also check the project's `url.py` There should be something like this: `url(r'^account/', include('account.urls', namespace='account'))`. Error still the same `Reverse for 'password_change_done'`?

Comment: Django 1.10 and projects urls.py url(r'^account/', include('account.urls', app_name='account', namespace='account')), and yes I am receiving the the same reverse error.

Comment: haha you were right the first time. I had a typo when I added your solution. So we are good to go. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely that your URLs are namespaced and you forgot to use the namespace.  Try:

```
{% url 'account:password_change_done' %}
```

or

```
reverse('account:password_change_done')
```

Remember to namespace your names, otherwise django might not be able to find them.  You can find the namespace that you are using (if it is not `account`) by looking at where you are including the urls for login, etc.  It should look something like:

```
url(r'account/', include('account.urls', namespace='account')),
```

Comment: I have not set any urls in my templates yet. My main urls is the same you have above and no luck

Comment: It can’t be your main urls file if you are accessing the page at `/account/password_change` as your stack trace implies.