# password_reset() got an unexpected keyword argument 'post_change_redirect'

Tags: python, django

I am facing some issues regarding reset password in django. I am using django's default authentication app in my app `accounts`. Here is the url definition:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^dashboard/$', dashboard, name='dashboard'),

    url(r'^login/$', views.login,
        {'template_name': 'accounts/login.html', 'authentication_form': LoginForm},
        name='login'),

    url(r'^logout/$', views.logout, {'next_page': '/accounts/login'}, name='logout'),

    url(r'^password/reset/$', views.password_reset,
        {
         'template_name': 'accounts/forgot_password.html',
         'password_reset_form': ForgotPasswordForm,
         },
        name='reset_password'),

    url(r'^password/reset/done', views.password_reset_done, name='password_reset_done'),

    url(r'^password/reset/verify/(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>,+)/$', views.password_reset_confirm, name='password_reset_confirm'),

]
```

But when I hit `/password/reset/` I was getting this error:

> Reverse for 'password_reset_done' with arguments '()' and keyword
>   arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

So i added `'post_change_redirect': 'accounts:password_reset_done',` argument in `/password/reset/` url according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41214510/reverse-for-password-change-done-with-arguments-and-keyword-arguments) answer.
Now I am getting this error

> password_reset() got an unexpected keyword argument 'post_change_redirect'

Comment: Just place `^password/reset/done` before `^password/reset/$` - without passing `post_change_redirect` parameter and check if it solved. Also it will be a lot better to have `^password/reset/done/$` to avoid problems with url.

Comment: no, not working. I could work around with changing `post_reset_redirect = reverse('password_reset_done')` to `post_reset_redirect = reverse('accounts:password_reset_done')` in django's `password_reset()` method. But that's not an solution. and any idea why `post_change_redirect` is not working?

Comment: Those `urls` are the root or the `account`'s ones?

Comment: actually it was a dumb mistake, i was providing `post_change_redirect` instead of `post_reset_redirect`. Guess mixed up with password change and password reset. @nik_m, those are account ones. My problem is fixed though.

Answer (score 1):

You will need all urls for built-in password reset:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import password_reset, password_reset_confirm, password_reset_complete

url(r'^password/reset/done/$', custom.password_reset_done, name='password-reset-done'),
url(r'^password/reset/complete/$', password_reset_complete, {'template_name': <template>}, name='password_reset_complete'),
url(r'^password/reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$', password_reset_confirm, {'template_name': <template>}, name='password_reset_confirm'),
url(r'^password/reset/$', password_reset, {'template_name': <template>, 'email_template_name': <template>, 'post_reset_redirect': 'password-reset-done'}, name='password-reset')
```

The only custom here will be `custom.password_reset_done`, just write your own view instead:

```
def password_reset_done(request):
    """Page after password reset."""
    return render(request, '<template path>', {})
```

In such cases using IDE to explore source code of these views helps a lot for defined required variables and etc.